# i need to run Google App script in onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm trying to create a script so that when I edit text in column A then it  automatically deletes text that is in column D of the same row and if column C in the same row (it contains ID of file from my drive) is not empty then delete that file.

I successfully created it and it's working when explicitly run the script in test , but the onEdit event never seems to get fired (not seeing log messages even).
anyone have an idea how it works ?

```
    function onEdit(e) {
  var currentSheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var sheetEdited = currentSheet.getName();
  var rowEdited = e.range.getRow();
  var columnEdited = e.range.getColumn();

  // if cell edited in sheet name form 1 and in column 1 then
  if(sheetEdited == "form 1" && ( columnEdited == 1)){ 
  // delete text in edited row column D
    currentSheet.getRange(rowEdited,4).setValue('');
  // if on edited row column C(that contain doc id ) if filled then detele that file 
   if (sheetId != "") {
         var sheetId = currentSheet.getRange(rowEdited,3).getValues();
         DriveApp.getFileById(sheetId).setTrashed(true);
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that simple triggers can't perform operations that require authorization.  So you have to use an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).  Don't forget to change the name of the function.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="form 1" &&  e.range.columnStart==1){ 
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,4).setValue('');//D
    var id=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,3).getValue();//C
    if(id!="")DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true);
  }
}
```